# Different with using.something

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating now web app in MVC 5.0 C# and my works stop because I have a little problem. I have class `Packs`, Interface `Packs` - `IPacksrepository`, and `PacksController`.

Packs.cs

```
namespace Domain.Entities
{
public class Packs
{
    public int PacksID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OwnerDescripiton { get; set; }
    public decimal wymiarX { get; set; }
    public decimal wymiarY { get; set; }
    public decimal wymiarZ { get; set; }
    public decimal Waga { get; set; }
    public string dataprzyjeciadomagazynu { get; set; }
    public string datawyslaniazmagazynu { get; set; }
    public string dataodebrania { get; set; }
    public int WarehousesID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("WarehousesID")]
    public Warehouses Warehouses { get; set; }

 }
}
```

`IPackRepostiory`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Domain.Entities;


namespace Domain.Abstract
{
public interface IPacksRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Packs> Packss { get; }

    void SavePacks(Packs packs);

    Packs DeletePacks(int PacksID);
 }
}
```

`PackController`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Domain.Entities;
using Domain.Abstract;
using WebUi.Models;

namespace WebUi.Controllers
{
public class PacksController : Controller
{
    private IPacksRepository repository;
    public int PageSize = 1;
    public PacksController(IPacksRepository packrepostiory)
    {
        this.repository = packrepostiory;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(repository.Packss);
    }
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(repository.Packss);
    }

    public ViewResult Create()
    {
        return View("Edit", new Packs());
    }
    public ActionResult Details(int? PacksID)
    {
       Packs packs = repository.Packss.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PacksID == PacksID);
       return View(packs);
    }



    public ViewResult Edit(int? PacksID)
    {
        Packs packss = repository.Packss.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PacksID == PacksID);
        return View(packss);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Packs packs)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            repository.SavePacks(packs);
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("Zapisano {0} ", packs.Name);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(packs);
        }


    }
    public ActionResult Delete(int PacksID)
    {
        Packs delpacks = repository.DeletePacks(PacksID);
        if (delpacks != null)
        {
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("Usunięto {0}", delpacks.Name);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
}
```

In my project I have a few class,`interfaces` and `Controllers` (like `persons`, `warehouses`, `transportfleet`) - All functions are structurally similar, differing only the data set.

All I "name" repository use `using Domain.Entities` and everything is OK, all working. `Domain.Entities` contains `Pack.cs` and others.
`IPacksRepostiory` even though it contains the name `using Domain.Entities` that is not used. By that I got errors in `PackController` like form `PackController`:

```
public ViewResult Edit(int? PacksID)
{
    Packs packss = repository.Packss.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PacksID == PacksID);
    return View(packss);
}
```

> repository.Packss.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PacksID == PacksID); ->
>   Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Domain.Entities.Packs'
>   to 'Domain.Packs'

Answer (score 1):

You could either use [`var`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) keyword instead:

```
var packss = repository.Packss.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PacksID == PacksID);
```

Or specify the qualifier and full type names implicitly to distinguish between ambiguous class names:

```
Domain.Entities.Packs packss = repository.Packss.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PacksID == PacksID);
```

Comment: Its not working, tell my please why others I"something"repository.cs is using Domain.Entities (Is highlighted) and when i implementing "using Domain.Entities" in Packs.cs , is not using ? (not highlighted)

Comment: @MikeEvans The `var` keyword should works unless I'm misunderstanding your question!

Comment: On certain cases, work but i want to know why in IPackRepository when i try use "using Domain.Entities" i cant? (is not highlighted). In other cases ( like IPersonRepository" i can use

Comment: @MikeEvans As I said you need to distinguish between ambiguous class names. It's because the compiler couldn't distinguish between them so you need do it implicitly.

Comment: Your answer solves half the things of which I had a problem

Comment: Please see a function "public ActionResult Edit". In line "                repository.SavePacks(packs);" i have this same problem (red highlighted packs)

Comment: And please tell my why IPacksRepostiory cant use "using Domain.Entities" but IPersonRepostiory can? this same structure (only dataset diffrents)

Comment: @MikeEvans Again you can specify the qualifier and full type names implicitly public ActionResult Edit(Domain.Entities.Packs packs)  -> its not working

Comment: @MikeEvans What do you mean by doesn't work exactly? Are you referenced the DLL's?

Comment: I did like you said "ActionResult Edit(Domain.Entities.Packs packs)" but visual studio didnt see Domain.Entities, i dont know why.... earlier everythings was fine, but all crushed when i connect Packs do Warehouse Database EF by foreign key

Comment: @MikeEvans Did you referenced the `Domain.Entities` DLL to your main project?

Comment: Yes, I referenced